# Conda environment hangs upon activation

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, virtual-environment

When I call `conda activate <my_env>` (or `source activate <my_env>`) on a specific environment, it hangs indefinitely: no output, no prompt back.

However, when I press Enter one or two times (or use CTRL+C), I get the prompt back and the environment seems to be activated and everything is working fine. It's basically the [exact same issue as described here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7468). I have few packages in common, like `django` and other `r` related packages.

I have:

```
conda                     4.6.4
conda-build               3.15.1
```

Running `conda config --get channels` gives:

```
--add channels 'defaults'   # lowest priority
--add channels 'bioconda'
--add channels 'conda-forge'   # highest priority
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was because there were some files in my conda environment that were owned by root.  I obviously must have accidentally thrown a `sudo` in front of a conda command at some point, which caused whatever files that were modified or created by that command to be left owned by root. Unless you want to always run your anaconda environment as root -- this would be rare and potentially very dangerous!! -- it would be highly advised to flip the ownership of those files back to your non-root user.

To accomplish this, I just simply did this at the shell:

```
$ cd ~/anaconda3
$ sudo chown -R user.user .
```

where you would replace `user` with your Linux username.

The default Ubuntu configuration creates a default group for each user that is the same name as the user, so that's why I put `user.user` in there.  If your setup is different, you can easily change that to match your situation.

If in doubt, just do an `ls -Fla ~/anaconda3` and it will show the owner and group information for all the files in the root of your Anaconda installation.

Comment: Thanks, I have no way of reproducing this bug now so I can't make sure your answer fixes the problem even though changing the permissions is the only thing I didn't try! If more people confirm that wrong permissions cause this behavior, I'll accept the answer.